# Tensorflow import_graph_def after quantization results in error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to generate an eightbit quantized graph for a custom LSTM model using TransformGraph. The graph import works fine if I only quantize_weights. Once  quantize_nodes is applied importing fails with an error as given below

> ValueError: Specified colocation to an op that does not exist during import: lstm1/lstm1/BasicLSTMCellZeroState/zeros in lstm1/lstm1/cond/Switch_2

The code snippet I an using for quantizing is listed below

```
from tensorflow.tools.graph_transforms import TransformGraph
import tensorflow as tf

input_names = ["inp/X"]
output_names = ["out/Softmax"]
#transforms = ["quantize_weights", "quantize_nodes"]
#transforms = ["quantize_weights"]
transforms = ["add_default_attributes",
"strip_unused_nodes",
"remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)",
#"fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)",
"fold_batch_norms",
"fold_old_batch_norms",
"quantize_weights",
"quantize_nodes",
"sort_by_execution_order"]
#output_graph_path="/tmp/fixed.pb"
output_graph_path="/tmp/output_graph.pb"
with tf.Graph().as_default():
        output_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            with open(output_graph_path, "rb") as f:

                output_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
                _ = tf.import_graph_def(output_graph_def, name="")

                transformed_graph_def = TransformGraph(output_graph_def, input_names,
                                       output_names, transforms)

                tf.train.write_graph(transformed_graph_def, '/tmp', 'quantized.pb', as_text=False)
```

I also tried using quantize_graph.py, which always resulted in a keyerror as in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8025. I believe this code is no longer maintained. Can anyone please point out how to debug this issue.

Comment: Seems like some issue with quantizing conditionals. CNN models work fine after quantization.